# Not able to launch chrome in protractor

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

While launching conf.js file in protractor its giving below error :

**ERROR [OsProcess.checkForError] - org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_87.0.4280.88" (in directory "."): error=86, Bad CPU type in executable)**

Comment: Its issue with webdriver-manager as its downloading m1 chromedriver on x86 machine. Currently there are two chromedriver for mac from 87 version .chromedriver_mac64_m1.zip & chromedriver_mac64.zip

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/476

Fix will be available soon this weekend. but you will get a workaround by doing this.

As I badly needed to get unblocked - here is a hacky workaround for anyone in similar situation (only for x86_64 macOS). In node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/files/file_manager.js update fileUrl.url around 166:

add below line

fileUrl.url = fileUrl.url.replace(/_m1/, '')

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the similar issue in MacOs Catalina.
This is how it got resolved for me with below versions :

**Option 1 :**
Download these :

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/71.0.3578.33/chromedriver_mac64.zip

https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.14/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar

And made the Selenium server UP with this :

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver_71.0.3578.33  -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
```

**Option 2 :**

Protractor :

Use the below versions :

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=71.0.3578.33
webdriver-manager --versions.chrome=71.0.3578.33 start
```

Answer (score 0):

Got an Error
"Timed out waiting for driver server to start." After running
`webdriver-manager update`

Resolved it by downgrading to the previous version of webdriver that was working for you.

Steps:

1. navigate to **node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/**
2. check if you can see the last chromedriver that you were using before the update
   [image]

for my case this is **chromedriver_86.0.4240.22**

3. since I still have my previous chromedriver, I just Deleted

- chromedriver_87.0.4280.88
- chromedriver_87.0.4280.88.zip

4. in node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/update-config.json
   I changed all instances of **chromedriver_87.0.4280.88** and replaced with **chromedriver_86.0.4240.22**
5. Run your tests.
6. Incase you dont know what was the last version that worked for you, you can try
   webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=86.0.4240.22
   or look for a version [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Update the protractor version to current stable version: `"protractor": "^7.0.0"`, npm install was the way to go for me, yours will be similar
2. Update the webdriver: `webdriver-manager update` with or without sudo is the right command as stated in other answers
3. Run the webdriver manager with the current chrome version, this is the command that I use for application: `webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=88.0.4324.96` as my chrome is currently at that version, replace it with your chrome's version (87.0.4280.88 as per the question)